# How do I disable auto-compilation of Scala source in jEdit?

Tags: scala, jedit

I have always liked the auto-compilation feature of jEdit with Scala sources. Now, however, I'm using "mvn scala:cc" and JavaRebel with a Lift project, which provides better compilation than what jEdit does, and I'd like to disable jEdit's auto-compilation.

How do I disable auto-compilation in jEdit, of Scala sources, in particular?

Comment: Once you figure this out, you might want to look at sbt.  the continuous compilation is much more robust-- it keeps track of dependent classes and will recompile them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using some sort of plugin which provides auto-compilation.  I use jEdit for Scala without any auto-compilation at all, simply by adding the `scala.xml` mode file to my .jedit/modes directory (along with the appropriate `catalog` entry).

In other words, I would just remove whatever plugin is causing auto-compilation; it's not actually necessary for Scala in jEdit.